# Unable to eject (unmount) USB drive

Tags: debian, xfce, usb-device

I'm on Debian Bullseye XFCE.  Please find the relevant details of my system below:

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ uname -a
Linux krishna 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-5 (2021-09-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try to eject my USB drive, I get the following error:

[image: error message]

I am experiencing this error only recently (2-3 days).
Can someone help me out?

Regards.

Comment: If this is a USB device then you **should** use `umount` command instead. `Eject` is usually used for Optical media like CD-ROM drives which don't need to flush data before disconnection. What is the reason behind using `eject` instead of `umount` ?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami: I meant the eject symbol in the sidebar of my file manager. Edited my question title.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Up-to-date `eject` is actually the right command. `man 1 eject` in Ubuntu states "if the device or a device partition is currently mounted, it is unmounted before ejecting". In my Debian `eject` is older, the manual says "if the device is currently mounted, it is unmounted before ejecting", so I don't know how well it handles mounted partitions in Debian. Anyway, sole `umount` unmounts a filesytem. `eject` is designed to flush to a block device and prepare it to be physically disconnected.

Comment: @kamil Yes. That's exactly what I mean. Also can someone edit my question so that the thumbnail of the screenshot can show up. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas What is the output of `type -a eject` in Bash? What is the output of `apt list --installed eject`? Maybe `eject` is not installed. In this case you need to invoke `sudo apt-get install eject`.

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas Hint: to embed a picture you need a link to the picture only. [The link you posted](https://imgur.com/MNeW9fU) is to a site where your picture can be seen along with other things; it's not a link to the picture itself.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I see. Historically this wasn't the case. `eject` seems to have gotten some features during the years. My man page on Fedora says the same.

Comment: Thanks @kamil. I don't know how, but `eject` was not installed. But previously I have many a times used to eject the USB drive directly from my file manager. Anyway, I have installed `eject`, and now everything works.

Comment: How can I Mark my question as "solved"

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas A question is considered solved when there is an [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). To accept an answer you need an answer. Currently there is no answer to your question, there are comments. Your comment that states the solution should be an answer. [Post an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @kamil. I don't know how, but `eject` was not installed. But previously I have many a times used to eject the USB drive directly from my file manager. Anyway, I have installed `eject,` and now everything works